# change the host header after the backend server responds

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a proxy setup to receive a client request for www.example.com from external.example.com (www.example.com is a tab on external.example.com) . the proxy recieves the request and sends to www.example2.com to the backend server with multiple websites with host headers. now when www.example2.com responds with path and query strings ex : https://www.example2.com/results . I want this intercepted by the proxy and have the proxy change just the header to http://www.example.com without going into a loop and display results . I have tried proxy_set-header host and proxy_redirect and both fail. below is my config :

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

   server_name www.example.com;

    #root /var/www/www.example.com;
    #index index.html;

   location / {
   proxy_pass http://www.example2.com;
  proxy_set_header Host http://www.example.com;
  OR
  Proxy_redirect https://www.example2.com$1 http://www.example.com
              }
           }
```

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_set_header Host www.example2.com`; without the `http://`?

Comment: @nbari if i set the host header to www.example2.com it will be the same url as the server which is not what we want . once we receive the response we want the host header to be the same as the requested client url which is www.example.com.If I set the host header to www.example.com , it ignores proxy_pass and jumps right to setting the host header , which means it never gets to the backend server.

Comment: probably using an upstream could help, I still don’t clearly understand what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @nbari here is the premise . one of our clients have a search website for certain type of  records they send some of the searches to us and we do the search in our databases and return the results to them . When they send us the request with query strings they have their host header and that comes to our proxy which then passes it along to www.example2.com in the above example. Once i do a proxy pass the host header is changed to our website host header . We want to rewrite the host header back to the original host header after getting the results which is http://www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a proxy_pass to a URL which was behind an aws elb . The elb was stripping out the set host header commands and proxy redirects . IO changed it to a prticular instance and it started working as expected. thanks for your help @nbari